# Alpha and Beta Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Q: Find all real polynomials of degree 3 with zeros -1/2 and 1-3i.

I figured the other zero would be 1+3i.

The sum of the roots (1-3i) and (1+3i) would be 2 and the product would be 1-9i^2=10

That turns one of the factors into (x^2-2x+10), but I am confused on where I get the other half of the equation.

Comment: you have another zero, -1/2. Can you make a factor from that?

Comment: oh yeah bruh it would turn into (2x+1) wouldn't it?

Comment: @Hayk yep! Now you know one polynomial with those roots. How do you think you should find all polynomials, like the question asks?

Comment: P(x)=a(x^2-2x+10)(2x+1), where a=/= 0?

Comment: @Hayk Welcome to Math SE. FYI, you may find [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) of use, if not here then possibly in some other cases.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).